# Using JavaScript to make a button react ( adding animation )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interactive

In the Code Academy platform, one activity asked me to code my own button and make it react when the user clicks it.
This is what they asked me.

Fill in the event handler below to apply the class `"btn-like"` to the `$(".btn")` element. Use `.toggleClass()` to apply the class. Use this to operate on the already-selected HTML element.

and this is the code they give me.

```
var main = function() {
   $(".btn").click(function() {


  });
 };

$(document).ready(main);
```

I tried different ways but none of them was successful.  What is the correct way to program the reaction?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-an-interactive-website/topics/jquery-events/jquery-click-try

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the hint button?

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question by adding the ways that you have tried, including the result(s) you obtained.

Answer (score 2):

```
var main = function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-like");
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: PLUS 9999 VERY USEFUL! I need to read more, thanks a lot for your cooperation!

Answer (score 1):

Just do what they've asked you to do within the `.click()` callback.

```
var main = function() { $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-like');
}); };

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: PLUS 9999 to you too, very useful I tried and ... It works! smoothly ! I need to apologize for don't know such easy things either way I'm in debt with you!

Answer (score 0):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/events/click-try.svg

That's the Hint button but for me, isn't a hint is more confusing